# Post one of two forms using a dropdown submit button

Tags: html, forms, dropdownbox, submit-button

I'm trying to post two different sets of mixed values. Each form will share some user submitted text like name and email.

```
<form method="post" action="url1">
<input type="hidden" name="donate" value="food">
<input type="hidden" name="days" value="30">
<input type="text" name="cans" value="5">
<input type="text" name="full_name" value="">
<input type="text" name="email" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="join1"/>
</form>

<form method="post" action="url1">
<input type="hidden" name="donate" value="shoes">
<input type="text" name="pairs" value="">
<input type="text" name="style" value="">
<input type="text" name="full_name" value="">
<input type="text" name="email" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="join2"/>
</form>

<possible dropdown>
```

It would be ideal to have Dropdown select between the two forms and submit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using only html you will get a problem as a submit button only submit its own form.
It's also not valid to have forms in other forms.

However, is a trick to accomplish your goal using javascript!

With a little function you can e.g. hide all other forms than one:

```
function showform(index){
    var forms = document.forms;
    for(var i=0;i<forms.length;i++)
        forms[i].style.display=(i==index?"block":"none");
}
```

Then you only need to add the onchange-event on your dropdown-list and hide one of the forms by default.
This would result in something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style language="css" type="text/css">
    form input{display:block;width:100px;}
</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showform(index){
    var forms = document.forms;
    for(var i=0;i<forms.length;i++)
        forms[i].style.display=(i==index?"block":"none");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select onchange='showform(this.selectedIndex);'>
<option>form1</option>
<option>form2</option>
</select>

<form  method="post" action="url1">
<input type="hidden" name="donate" value="food"/>
<input type="hidden" name="days" value="30"/>
<input type="text" name="cans" value="5"/>
<input type="text" name="full_name" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="email" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="join1"/>
</form>

<form id='form2' style='display:none' method="post" action="url2">
<input type="hidden" name="donate" value="shoes"/>
<input type="text" name="pairs" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="style" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="full_name" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="email" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="join2"/>
 </form>

</body></html>
```

If you don't like javascript, you would need to do that in php by using an additional form for the select-element and insert only the wanted form (or hide the others).

Answer (score 0):

I already see some design issues with the way you have planned your multi-form setup, there are much better techniques to handle this - but I will try to help you using your own technique.

By using your own example, this should work for you:

```
<form id="join1" method="post" action="url1">
<input type="hidden" name="donate" value="food">
<input type="hidden" name="days" value="30">
<input type="text" name="cans" value="5">
<input type="text" name="full_name" value="">
<input type="text" name="email" value="">
</form>

<form id="join2" method="post" action="url1">
<input type="hidden" name="donate" value="shoes">
<input type="text" name="pairs" value="">
<input type="text" name="style" value="">
<input type="text" name="full_name" value="">
<input type="text" name="email" value="">
</form>

<select id="formList">
<option value="">Select form..</option>
<option value="join1">Join1</option>
<option value="join2">Join2</option>
</select>
<button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
```

And this is the javascript for making it happen (using jQuery):

```
$('#submitBtn').on('click',function(){
    var selectedForm = $('#formList').val();
    if(selectedForm){
        $('#'+ selectedForm).submit();
    }
});
```

the example is also available as a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/k1jf4b4L/

Hope it helps a bit